# Azure DevOps, specifically Pipelines, not Releases

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, specifically Pipelines, not Releases I want to make it compulsory when someone releases a pipeline, they must add a comment, specifically a Change Request number in the comment ….Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not really possible. The YAML pipelines don't offer a way to present UI to people. There is a standard "comment" box when you do an approval, but that can't be extended.

The trick most people do is to have a job that reaches out to whatever change request system you use and then looks up the change request by the ID/URL of the release and thus register the change at the other end. And fail the job if that's not there. You can then retry the release until the stuff is there.